# Can't use set_ydata for a "stem"-plot in matlibplot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I can't use the set_ydata method properly. I have the following code (I use IPython notebook)

```
%pylab wx
x = arange(20.)
y_old = x**2
y_new = 1.3*y_old

markerline, stemlines, baseline = stem(x,y_old)
markerline.set_ydata(y_new)
```

Which results in the following picture:

[image: stem-plot]

I tried to add:

```
stemlines.set_ydata(y_new)
baseline.set_ydata(y_new)
```

but the programm crashed. What can be done to refresh all elements of the stem-plot?

Comment: what is your expected result? If you just want a new plot with y_new as input, just call `show()` after the first `stem()`-call and plot y-new with `stem(x,y_new)`. By the way, what do you need markerline, stemlines, baseline for? For a detailed overview of the stem()-method, also have a look at this [link](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/stem.html)

Comment: In the future, please provide the trace back, 'it crashes' is accurate, but useless information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need for loop the stemlines, and set the y_data for every line:

```
x = arange(20.)
y_old = x**2
y_new = 1.3*y_old

markerline, stemlines, baseline = stem(x,y_old)
markerline.set_ydata(y_new)
for line, y in zip(stemlines, y_new):
    line.set_ydata([0, y])
```